# pass arraylist from one activity to other

Tags: android

How can I pass `ArrayList` from one activity to other activity?

Answer (score 42):

It depends on the type of arraylist

- `putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value)`
- `putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`
- `putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)`
- `putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<CharSequence> value)`

Then you can read from you next activity by replacing `put` with `get` with key string as argument,eg

```
myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayPeople");
```

Comment: @LabeebP How to pass ArrayList<Object> to another class

Answer (score 4):

You can create one bundle in bundle put parceable array list provided by labeeb and set to intent here is the code for

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,name.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value);
//b.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value);
//b.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value);
i.putExtra(String name,b);
startActivity(i);
```

And get data into another activity like

```
//pseudo code
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra().putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, create static class and put your array-list in it while you traverse from one activity to the other.

When you reach in another activity, access the value that you stored in the static class.

**UPDATE**
I've learned with time that it's a horrible practice. When the objects are wiped/recreated the Static values might be lost. and then we put a lot of data in memory too. Using anything like Parcelable is a good practice

Comment: Using static fields to transfer data from one activity to another is a really bad design :/

Comment: And why so!? if only a small number of values are concerned!?

Comment: Because when the user does things like go BACK or onPause() etc. the app still thinks the variables are in memory when they aren't and the app FCs. I learnt the hard way :-)

Comment: Thanks! I am also learning it the hard way :p  See that 3 downvotes! :(

Comment: @ValentinRocher Can you please explain me why its bad to pass the data in static field from one activity to another.If you have any link then its well and good for me.

Comment: @InfinitiFizz Can you please explain me why its bad to pass the data in static field from one activity to another.If you have any link then its well and good for me.

Comment: Well @nick its my answer and I've also learned that it's a horrible practice. When the objects are wiped/recreated the Static values might be lost. and then we put a lot of data in memory too. Using anything like Parcelable is a good practice

Answer (score 0):

In revoked Activity you should use

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();             
ArrayList<String> stringArray = bundle.getStringArrayList(ParentActivity.STRING_LIST);
```

where `ParentActivity.STRING_LIST` is your key constant for the list.

Answer (score -2):

When you create intent. you can set data by

```
intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
```

when intent B start you can get data by

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null)
{
   String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}
```

Comment: Its an ArrayList, not a String.

Comment: im unable to get those values...im geting null value... thanks in advance