# passing arrays using bundle in android

Tags: android, arrays, bundle

I need to pass an array of String/integer values from one Activity to another. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In activity A:

```
String[] abc;

Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("some string",abc);
```

In Activity B where you want to get give the code as:

```
String abcd[]=bundle.getStringArray("some string");
```

"some string" should be same in both case.

Comment: hey niki thanks!!...but have u ever tried this because the various sites i have visited have mentioned that u can not pass array using a bundle...is that true??

Answer (score 5):

At the sender side, the code should be:

```
String[] myStrings=new String[2];
myStrings[0]="MONDAY";
myStrings[1]="TUESDAY";
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Animation_program.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);
intent.putExtras(bundle);               
startActivity(intent);
```

At the reciever side, the code should be:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras=i.getExtras();

if(extras != null)  //this line is necessary for getting any value
{
    String[] fajr_Values = i.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
    Toast.makeText(this, "value="+fajr_Values[0]+""+fajr_Values[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never passed an array using a bundle, and I do not know off the top of my head if it can be done, but you can certainly pass an ArrayList (or anything Serializable/Parcelable). See this question for a more complete answer:

[Passing data of a non-primitive type between activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441871/passing-data-of-a-non-primitive-type-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [pass arraylist from one activity to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780835/pass-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-other/4781032#4781032) may help you

Comment: Plz check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350646/   I fail to pass string array data to next swipe view fragment

Answer (score -2):

Code for pass String And Integer value ::

In Your First Activity ::

```
Intent intent = new Intent(California.this,details.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Keyname1", StringValue);
bundle.putInt("Keyname2", IntegerValue);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Second Activity :

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String s=b.getString("Keyname1");
int i=b.getInt("Keyname2");
```

Comment: String and integer are not arrays.