# Call fragment method inside Activity's oncreate method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to call fragment method from main activity.But my app is crashing

This is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
    ActionBar.TabListener,ConversationFragment.OnGetFromUserClickListener {
         ConversationFragment frgObj;
         Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>> table = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            addMessageToFragment("test");
    }

public void addMessageToFragment(String message) {
    Log.w("Step 1",message);
    table.put("tolgay", new ArrayList<Message>());
    table.get("tolgay").add(new Message("asda", "asda"));
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    frgObj=ConversationFragment.newInstance(table.get("tolgay"));
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, frgObj,"ConversationFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    frgObj.addMessageToList("asd");

}
}
```

What is wrong with this code ? I want to load fragment with some data in oncreate method.How can I fix it ?

Here logcat:http://goo.gl/id4UmY

Comment: What's on row 342 where the NPE occurs? What does `table.get("tolgay")` return?

Comment: And for future reference, please include logcat in the question itself as text.

Comment: Line 342:table.get("tolgay").add(new Message("asda", "asda"));

Comment: There is a null pointer exception. Is the container inside the activity_main layout? Just wondered.

Comment: @laalto I updated my code can you check again ? Now table.get("tolgay") is not returning null

Comment: So did the stacktrace change?

Comment: @laalto No,still crashing:http://prntscr.com/4ecdf9

Comment: Now the NPE is in `ConversationFragment.java:90` so it's a different problem. And please, stacktrace as text.

Comment: why do not you put logcat in the question?

Comment: @laalto it's adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); I defined adapter in oncreateview like this :   adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strArr);

Answer (score 0):

Your NPE is on this row:

```
 table.get("tolgay").add(new Message("asda", "asda"));
```

Since `table` is non-null by initialization, the only possibility for a NPE here is that `table.get("tolgay")` returns null. The hashtable doesn't contain a message with such key. Use `put()` to insert new keys in case one didn't exist.

Also consider using `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`. In UI code like this running in a single thread you don't need the synchronization provided by `Hashtable`.

Comment: I updated my code,can you check again ? My app is still crashing.Logcat:http://prntscr.com/4ecdf9

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions would be to simply create your fragment instance, add Bundle and then use the **setArguments()** methods to set it on the fragment. Just make sure the data you are setting is not null.

Then while in your fragment (could be inside onAttach or onCreate or onActivityCreated method, just use this:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
```

Then retrieve the data that you added before.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I can't do it because I am passing arraylist.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a bundle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299532/passing-arrays-using-bundle-in-android or you might have to use a different approach if you cannot modify the data structure to use primities; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441871/passing-data-of-a-non-primitive-type-between-activities-in-android