# problems sending 2d array to another layout android eclipse java

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

I'm creating an android application with 2 layouts.
In one layout the user input data and I would like to keep this data and use it on a different layout.

I try using 2d array, but it seems that array values are not sent to the second layout.

On my first layout

```
grid = new double[2][long];
for( int i=0; i<long; i++ )
{
    grid[0][i]=Data[i];
    grid[1][i]=Value2;  
}

public double[][] sendGrid() 
{
    return grid;
}
```

When I want to call the 2d grid array on the second Layout I have...

```
try{
    Layout1 mapInstance = new Layout1y();
    double[][] dataX = mapInstance.sendGrid();
    Log.i("dataXLength",""+dataX.length);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.i("-OK",e.toString());
}
```

The result is: 04-13 10:31:45.357: I/-OK(28588): `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Any idea on how can I send the 2d array to my second layout?

Thank you

Comment: use shared preferences or pass the grid value through the intent.

Comment: Please post compilable Java code.

Comment: I will test intent and let you know, thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780835/pass-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are couple of methods to do that but i think in your case  its best suited if you make your 2d array static.

```
static double grid = new double[2][long];
```

Now in next activity access like this

```
double[][] dataX =Activity1.grid[][];
```

Comment: This option seems to be very simple.  Thank you very much, it is working now!

Comment: @GerardoAbdo You should use intents to pass data between activities. Using static variables is not recommended. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. The guy in the video gives a big warning using static variables. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic.

Answer (score 0):

By "Layout", I assume you mean "Activity".
You have a number of options to pass data between activities, all of which are explained nicely on this question:
[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)